# How to write an enum as a class?

Tags: java, serialization, enums

In my project, I manipulate instances of the following class :

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable{

    private MyEnum model;
    
    private Object something; //NOT TRANSIENT
    
    public MyClass(MyEnum model){
        
        this.model = model;
        //something = ...
        
    }
    
}
```

Every instance of `MyClass` is created by passing it a model

```
public enum MyEnum{
    
    A,
    B,
    C,
    //A lot more of these...
    ;
    
}
```

I often have to serialize/deserialize instances of `MyClass`, this is why I marked its field `something` as NOT transient.

The behavior is such that :

1. During serialization, `something` and the "identifier" of `model` will be serialized.
2. During deserialization, `something` will be deserialized and `model` will be equal to what it was before, without having to deserialize it since it's an enum.

But I have so many of these models that I'm getting for my enum :

"The code for the static initializer is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit"

What is the proper way to fix this problem? How to write this enum as a class to work around this limitation?

Comment: Please include a [mre] that demonstrates the problem and adds more clarification, including how it will be used, serialization, etc.  Skeletal code does not  help portray the issue.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "write an enum as a class" - I don't understand what you mean. Can you explain in more detail what exactly you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

Having such large `enum`s does not make sense. Don't you think that you have too much data in there?

You are using `enums` as a way to map between unique object instances and string names. So replace your enums with another type, for example, `String`.

##### TL;DR

You cannot use `enum` for what you require. It does not work. You could use an `ArrayList` or `array` with `Strings` which is filled through a `file` or `db` .